# Connection to Entity Framework from SSIS-package script task

Tags: frameworks, ssis, connection, entity

From a script task in a SSIS-package I am calling a method in a DLL that uses Entity Framework. And when I´m debugging it stops in the DLL.

Error message: "The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, 
not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid"

I had this error before, when I used the DLL from a website, but then I copied the Entity Framework Model Connection to the web.config, and it worked just fine.

What do I have to do in my script task in SSIS? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Your entity model assumes an application configuration file (such as web.config) exists, but because this is an SSIS package, the configuration model is different.

You need to add an SSIS configuration, put your entity connection string in there, map this into a variable in the package and then have the script task supply the connection string as an argument in the constructor of the data model. So something like:

```
EntityModel MyModel = new EntityModel(this.Dts.Variables["EntityConnectionString"]);
```

...and you should be good to go.